# I have just made my first wxwidgets project in codeblocks, I want an application that just runs my GUI directly. Kindly Help Me

Tags: c++, user-interface, codeblocks, wxwidgets, software-distribution

I have made my wxwidgets project in codeblocks, I need a way to run my GUI directly like most applications run on a PC(like calculator , calender etc..). I don't want to go to codeblocks and build & run my program again and again. I need to make an exe file to just run it by clicking and my GUI directly starts running.

Comment: When you build the program it creates an executable *somewhere* - you just need to find it and use that

Comment: It creates and executable in [projectname.cbp]/bin/Debug, but when I try to open it, it gives an error. Both in linux as well as in windows.

Comment: @SameerYadav, could you please cut'n'paste the error message please? Also, it would help if you provide the way you build wxWidgets? Or you downloaded the pre-built binaries? Anyway - we need more info, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already compiled your code, an executable file can be found in the output folder. With that file, u can execute your code directly without any build, because the code has already been built.

I'm using g++ as the compiler on WSL, for me I do this:

```
g++ MyApp.cxx `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` -o MyApp.exe
```

then I run it like all other apps.